# Store File Locally via Mongoose Crate with MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up [Mongoose Crate](https://github.com/achingbrain/mongoose-crate) with my REST API using the MEAN stack. I'm pretty new to the whole thing so take it easy on me. I want to be able to upload a file to a local directory and then display that image within the controller. My route is setup as follows:

```
router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  // Mongoose Crate attach method
  post.attach('image', req.files.image, function(err, post) {
  if(err){ return next(err); }
    post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }
      res.json(post);
    });
  });

});
```

This is my Post model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crate = require('mongoose-crate');
var LocalFS = require('mongoose-crate-localfs');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String
});

PostSchema.plugin(crate, {
  storage: new LocalFS({
    directory: './public/uploads'
  }),
  fields: {
    image: {}
  }
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('FeedCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'posts',
  function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.addPost = function() {
      posts.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        author: $scope.author,
        image: $scope.image
      });
      $scope.title = '';
    }

  }
]);
```

And on the front end:

```
<form ng-submit="addPost()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title">
  </div>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>

<div>
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
  <img src="{{post.image}}"/> 
  <span>posted by <a>{{post.author}}</a></span>
</div>
```

I read that by using Express you can get an uploaded file by just the input name and using `req.files` but I can’t seem to get that too work within the scope. If I’m reading that Mongoose Crate plugin correctly, it should save it to a directory of your choice (using the mongoose-crate-localfs plugin), by adding it to the “Post” model, and send back an array of the file meta data. I'm not able to retrieve any data after the post.

I feel like that scene in Seinfeld when they’re trying to write the script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9eDwHznMas. “Now we need something here…”. I just don’t know what it is. If someone can please take a look and please get me out of this funk that would be amazing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Express does not come with a multipart parser out of the box, `req.files` will be undefined if you are not using a multipart parsing middleware. A good multipart middleware to check out is [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), very easy to use. Also if you are planning making this an XHR request you will need to use the `FormData` api, and explicitly tell angular not to process the data. Im sure there are many good third party solutions but here is an [article](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) worth reading.